# Android and Facebook SDK - Post on Page wall like a page

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-3.0

I have a big issue, I'm developing a App for android, this app need post images on Wall Pages of facebook.

The only place I can post anything, is on "Recent Posts by Others People", and I need post the image on "main" wall.

So, I need Upload the image like Page and no like a User.

Can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at/use the [Simple Facebook library](https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook/tree/master/Simple%20Facebook) over at github.

It's a library that simplifies the use of Facebook interfaces; among them there's a method to post photographs and to interact with the newsfeed.

Comment: I'm using this, and work very well, but the problem is, when I post something on page, he post that on "Recent Posts by Others People".

Comment: Do you mean what you see when you click "News" or "Newsfeed on the right side? (That's where you publish with the publishFeedExample).

Comment: Yes, the "Recent Posts by Others on PAGE_NAME". In the middle of page you have 3 options, "Highlights", "Posted By Page" and "Posted By Others", my submits appears on "Posted By Others", and I want they appears on "Posted By Page"..